# Android: Prepend LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, prepend

I created a layout in my application that includes the followings:
`main_layout` (`FrameLayout`, fills whole screen)
-> includes: `main_interface` (`LinearLayout`, height/width fills parent)

Now I want to add another `LinearLayout` in the `main_layout` BEFORE the `main_interface`.
I tried this:

```
LinearLayout bar = new LinearLayout(this);
        bar.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        bar.setLayoutParams(params);
        main_layout.addView(bar);
```

but this just overlaps my `main_interface`.
Any Help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to add a `View` to specific position in a `ViewGroup`, you can use `addView(view, position)`. In this case, assuming `main_interface` is the first `View`, you can call `main_layout.addView(bar, 0)`.

However, you need to fix your layout first. If you use `FrameLayout` as your `main_layout` and set `main_interface` height and width to `match_parent`, then they will surely overlap. Try making your `main_layout` a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` if you want vertically stacked `View`s.

If you could post your actual XML layout, I could help you modify and test it.

Comment: Thanks, you were right in every point! I changed the Layout to LinearLayout and set the index off addView() to zero. THANKS!